# How to override /etc/nanorc systemwide?

Tags: configuration, nano

I want all users of nano to have `tabsize 4` instead of the default 8. What is the best way to achieve this? I would prefer a file that overrides /etc/nanorc at the system level so I don't have to maintain separate user nanorc's for this purpose. In the simple case, my override would only need to contain:

```
set tabsize 4
```

Here's another way to state my question: Does nano recognize /etc/nanorc.d/ and config files placed therein? If so, what is the required naming and/ content of config files placed there?

What I tried so far was to create `/etc/nanorc.d/` and place a file named tabsize.conf in that directory and put only the following contents in the file:

```
set tabsize 4
```

My naive attempt did not work, but I am hoping there is a way to use this config.d/ pattern with nano.

I will make my question even more specific. I am using Arch Linux. I have do do these steps when the package has a new nanorc:

```
mv /etc/nanorc.pacnew /etc/nanorc
```

Then edit `/etc/nanorc`, search for tabsize, uncomment the line, change the value from 8 to 4 and save the file.

My goal is to only have to do this step:

```
mv /etc/nanorc.pacnew /etc/nanorc
```

And to have a file similar to `/etc/nanorc.d/tabsize.conf` that contains my desired tab size. It's a small savings of time, but multiplied across a number of computers it adds up. This year it seems like I have gotten new `/etc/nanorc.pacnew` files about six times. It is very inefficient to keep editing tabsize over and over.

Comment: Isn't a solution modifying `/etc/nanorc`?

Comment: @IporSircer no, because `/etc/nanorc` gets over-written on package updates and I am constantly having to edit it to once again set tabsize 4. I'm trying to avoid that.

Comment: Any custom settings to files in /etc won't be overwritten on upgrades by default, unless you have force it with switches. This is how every distribution works.

Comment: @IporSircer of course. Sorry I wasn't clear. It's the manual work I am trying to avoid. I wish to be able to simply use the packager's version of the updated nanorc without having to repeat my customization every time. It's a common pattern for many packages, and I am asking if there is a way to achieve the same thing with nano.

Comment: Again: this is how a distribution works. Configuration of Apache, Proftpd, Squid, Mysql and any other programs store their huge config files in /etc, and sysadmins do upgrades without problems. In Debian you can set **triggers** which are activated after a specific package was installed. You can make a custom trigger to append one line to `/etc/nanorc` on every updates. This is the clean way.

Comment: @IporSircer See update to question. You are answering a different question from the one I am asking. I am asking about the config.d/ pattern of overriding package-supplied versions of config files. That's also very common, widely used. I want to find out how to do it with nano.

Comment: Nano -and most of the programs- doesn't support directory based config files. Look at the source of nano and feel free to make a patch.

Comment: patching nano is beyond my ability, but I can write a script using sed to automate the file editing process.

Comment: That's called **trigger**, what i've talked about.

Comment: Oops, update! There is a line in nanorc: `include "/usr/share/nano/*.nanorc"`. But i don't know if your distro overwrites those files.

Comment: @IporSircer Thank you. I'll try that. I have not advanced to the point of reading source code yet. :-) I appreciate your help.

Comment: `/usr/share/nano/tabsize.nanorc` did not work for me.

Comment: The `include` command in `nanorc` is only for syntax highlighting. `man nanorc`: `Read in self-contained color syntaxes from syntaxfile.  Note that syntaxfile may contain only the above commands, from syntax to icolor.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So `/etc/nanorc.pacnew` is the new rc file that came with the new distribution upgrade? How about

```
sed '/tabsize/ {s/^# *//; s/[0-9]*$/4/}' /etc/nanorc.pacnew > /etc/nanorc
```

, then?

Another possible trick might be to have a symbolic link `~/.nanorc` in every user's home dir pointing to a central file with the relevant commands.

on demand:

```
sed '/tabsize/              # if the line matches "tabsize"
{s/^# *//;                  # remove "#" and trailing spaces from begin-of-line (BOL)
s/[0-9]*$/4/                # substitute any sequence of digits at EOL by "4"
}' /etc/nanorc.pacnew       # input file
> /etc/nanorc               # redirection to target file
```

Comment: I like both suggestions. I'll probably use sed. Can you walk me through the sed command? Also, the .pacnew (the file that came with the new package upgrade) contains this line: `#set tabsize 8` with an initial comment character and possibly variable white space. It needs to be transformed into `set tabsize 4` without the comment.

Comment: UPDATE: I tested your sed solution and it works perfectly. Thanks. Just wish I understood it better.

Comment: added explanation.

Answer (score 1):

To add to RudiC's answer, the link trick works! This is good for global overrides that you don't need to fix after e.g. a `do-release-upgrade` on Ubuntu (which may update the `/etc/nanorc` file).

Here's what I did.
Let's say the shared nanorc override file is in `/home-shared/.config/nano/nanorc`
Then just link it for each user (`su $USER`):

```bsh
mkdir -p ~/.config/nano &&
ln -s /home-shared/.config/nano/nanorc ~/.config/nano/nanorc
```

You can do the same for root user as well, so it also applies when using `sudo nano ...`:

```bsh
sudo mkdir -p /root/.config/nano &&
sudo ln -s /home-shared/.config/nano/nanorc /root/.config/nano/nanorc
```

In this case, it's probably best to make sure the linked file is only writable by root:

```bsh
sudo chown root:root /home-shared/.config/nano/nanorc &&
sudo chmod 644 /home-shared/.config/nano/nanorc # 0644/-rw-r--r--
```

---

An example of a nanorc file which I like, to make it more like GUI editors:

```bsh
## Forget the used search/replace strings on the next session.
unset historylog
## Display line numbers to the left (and any anchors in the margin).
set linenumbers
## Disable vim-style lock-files.
unset locking
## Make the Home key smarter, toggling line-start / first non-whitespace position
set smarthome
## Spread overlong lines over multiple screen lines.
set softwrap
## Disallow nano to be suspended (with ^Z by default).
unset suspendable
## Use this tab size instead of the default; it must be greater than 0.
set tabsize 2
## Make nano have keybindings that are more "usual"
bind ^Q exit all
bind ^S savefile main
bind ^W writeout main
bind ^O insert main
bind ^H help all
bind ^H exit help
bind ^F whereis all
bind ^G findnext all
bind ^R replace main
bind ^X cut all
bind ^C copy main
bind ^V paste all
bind ^A mark main
bind ^Z undo main
bind ^Y redo main
```

Answer (score 0):

[The Nano documentation](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/nanorc.5.html) for Nano 6.4 says that `nano --rcfile=/pathtonanorcfile` makes it so it doesn't load other nanorc files.

"During startup, if −−rcfile is not given, nano will read two files: first the system-wide settings, from /etc/nanorc (the exact path might be different on your system), and then the user-specific settings, either from ~/.nanorc or from $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/nano/nanorc or from ~/.config/nano/nanorc, whichever is encountered first. If −−rcfile is given, nano will read just the specified settings file."

To disable nanorc file reading altogether, do `nano -I`.